# Printing Image to Zebra iMZ320

Tags: c#, bitmap, zebra-printers, windows-mobile-6.5

Platform: Windows Mobile 6.5 Handheld

Language: C#

My problem: I'm being asked to capture a signature from the user and then send that signature to a printer to print on a receipt. I've successfully captured the image of the signature and have the byte array of the signature in memory but cannot seem to print it properly.

To get me started, I followed the [blog here](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.com/2007/08/printing-bitmaps-using-cpcl.html) to get the Hex representation of the bitmap. However, this just printed out a very long receipt with the hex 
representation of the signature. Code here instead of following the link:

```
    private static string DrawBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int xPosition, int yPosition)
    {
        if (bmp == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bmp");

        StringBuilder DataString = new StringBuilder();
        //Make sure the width is divisible by 8
        int loopWidth = 8 - (bmp.Width % 8);
        if (loopWidth == 8)
            loopWidth = bmp.Width;
        else
            loopWidth += bmp.Width;

        //DataString.Append(string.Format("EG {0} {1} {2} {3} ", xPosition, yPosition));
        DataString.Append(string.Format("EG 64 128 {0} {1} ", xPosition, yPosition));

        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            int bit = 128;
            int currentValue = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < loopWidth; x++)
            {
                int intensity;

                if (x < bmp.Width)
                {
                    Color color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    intensity = 255 - ((color.R + color.G + color.B) / 3);
                }
                else
                    intensity = 0;

                if (intensity >= 128)
                    currentValue |= bit;
                bit = bit >> 1;
                if (bit == 0)
                {
                    DataString.Append(currentValue.ToString("X2"));
                    bit = 128;
                    currentValue = 0;
                }
            }//x
        }//y
        DataString.Append("\r\n");

        return DataString.ToString();
    }
```

After that failed, I found the  [CPCL programming guide](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/813785/Zebra-Cpcl.html?page=95#manual) for Zebra printers and followed the example on page 95 to print the little tile image. However, this did the same thing as the signature. Once that failed, I found that I needed to run the command: `! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"` before doing any EG commands; so I went ahead and did this but things took a bad turn here which end up forcing me to fully reset the printer and/or cleanboot the handheld because it causes a COM exception that crashes COM6 and the printer.

I have exhausted most if not all of the resources that I can think of and none of them have worked.

Does anyone have any other ideas or examples that could help me get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Does this work: http://mrpmorris.blogspot.fr/2007/08/printing-bitmaps-using-cpcl.html. Most times when the printer prints the code instead of the text or image it is due to being set to an alternate printer language. AND, often the transfer is a problem, most printers understand ASCII-7 only. So the DataString might be translated to a 7Bit byte array before being sent to the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another CPCL programmers guide and it has this simple (test) example:

```
! 0 200 200 210 1
EG 2 16 90 45 F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F00F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F00F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
FORM
PRINT
```

This should print a small checker board pattern.

The next example prints a PCX graphic:

```
PCX Commands
The PCX command gives a user the ability to send “.PCX” graphics formatted images to the printer. The
.PCX image MUST be encoded as a black and white image.
Format:
{command} {x} {y}
{data}
where:
{command}: PCX
{x}: X-coordinate of the top-left corner.
{y}: Y-coordinate of the top-left corner.
{data}: PCX image data.
```

Example:

```
! 0 200 200 500 1
PCX 0 30
<binary black and white pcx data stream>
FORM
PRINT
```

Example using a file (loaded previously the printers file system)

```
! 0 200 200 500 1
PCX 0 30 !<IMAGE.PCX
FORM
PRINT
```

If the printer has been switched to line printer mode, the command

```
! U1 PCX {x coordinate} {y coordinate} !< {filename.pcx}
```

for example

```
! U1 PCX 0 30 !< IMAGE.PCX
```

can be used to print monochrome PCX from file system.

Remeber that .NET is UTF-8 and so all commands and data has to be converted to ASCII before sending over a COM port. So do something like this:

```
        Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        byte[] buf = ansi.GetBytes(DataString);
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1:");
        sp.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

for the PCX data just use the byte stream for the byte[] buffer.

Comment: I was able to successfully print the checkboard and a few other images that I tried.I was talking with the person of the project I'm working on and he brought up that I need to support an Intermec printer as well as the Zebra printer. Am I able to use these methods for both, or will it have to be conditional based on the printer?

Comment: Although some Intermec printers support ZSim (a Zebra CPCL simulation), some do not. So best would be to have separate implementations based on an Interface class. PS: why does it work for you now? What was the trick?

Comment: Well, I've got it working using Zebra Utilities, rather than through the application I'm writing currently. I believe my problem in the application is that I am attempting to change from line print mode to zpl mode in the middle of the print buffer. So, I believe I'm going to have to either switch entirely to zpl print mode or do send multiple print jobs. Another large part of my problem was that I needed to compress the bits that are passed and my algorithm for the compression was not working properly with the parameters I was passing to the EG command. I appreciate your help on this.